# Was UN security council resolution 242 binding?

Tags: international, war, united-nations, un-security-council

From what I understand, [UN security council resolutions are binding](https://unrcca.unmissions.org/sites/default/files/6-unrcca_handout_unsc_resolutions_eng_2020_1_2.pdf), in contrast to general assembly resolutions which are not. [This fine page](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/international-law-and-the-arabisraeli-conflict/un-security-council-resolution-242/54A855BC5E1413FE27B39B6F8B52EE97) from Cambridge, which is a body that is generally trusted in the field, states:

> UN Security Council Resolution 242, adopted after the June 1967 Six Day War, was a non-binding recommendation for settling the Arab-Israel conflict.

**Was [UN security council resolution 242](https://peacemaker.un.org/middle-east-resolution242) binding or not?** If not, why not? If partially, which parts, and why? If it was binding only on certain parties, on which parties, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolution 242 was adopted under [Chapter VI](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/chapter-6) (not [Chapter VII](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/chapter-7)) of the *UN Charter* (see [Security Council Official Record S/PV.1382](https://web.archive.org/web/20171012112540/https://unispal.un.org/DPA/DPR/unispal.nsf/0/9F5F09A80BB6878B0525672300565063), 22 November 1967).

There is an [advisory opinion](https://www.icj-cij.org/advisory-jurisdiction) from the [International Court of Justice](https://www.icj-cij.org/home) ([*Legal Consequences for States of the Continued Presence of South Africa in Namibia (South West Africa) notwithstanding Security Council Resolution 276 (1970)*, Advisory Opinion, 1971](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908063122/http://www.icj-cij.org/docket/files/53/5594.pdf)) that *all* U.N. Security Council resolutions are binding.

But, there is disagreement on this point from international law scholars, and the Security Council itself does not treat its resolutions outside of [Chapter VII](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter/chapter-7) to be binding (see Frowein, Jochen Abr. Völkerrecht – Menschenrechte – Verfassungsfragen Deutschlands und Europas, Springer, 2004, p. 58; as cited and translated at [Wikipedia: United Nations resolution, footnote 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=United_Nations_resolution&oldid=1142528966)).

Comment: I see, thank you!